# MATLAB var function returns weird results

Tags: matlab, statistics

I get different results when using MATLAB's [var](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/var.html) function, in compare to when calculating it based on the variance formula.

My input is:

```
x = [1,1,1,2];
```

when I use var function I get:

```
var(x)

ans =
0.2500
```

when I calculate the variance by using the variance formula I get:

```
mean((x-mean(x)).^2)

ans =
0.1875
```

where the variance formula is defined by

[image]

Does anyone knows what is the cause for this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the description / help of matlab for the function `var` it says that the sum is normalized by default with `N-1` instead of `N` that is why you get different results:

```
x = [1,1,1,2];

mean_x=mean(x);

var1=sum((x-mean_x).^2)/length(x)
var2=sum((x-mean_x).^2)/(length(x)-1)
```

var1 =

```
0.1875
```

var2 =

```
0.2500
```

You can find [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17890/what-is-the-difference-between-n-and-n-1-in-calculating-population-variance) a discussion about the difference of using `N-1` rather than `N`. `Var` allows you to choose between both normalization by setting the second parameter to `0 default N-1` or `1 for N`

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on to the point above

> V = var(A,w) specifies a weighting scheme. When w = 0 (default), V is
>   normalized by the number of observations-1. When w = 1, it is
>   normalized by the number of observations. w can also be a weight
>   vector containing nonnegative elements. In this case, the length of w
>   must equal the length of the dimension over which var is operating.

Thus, doing var(x,1) will give you the correct answer

[Matlab reference](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/var.html)